# jQuery: refresh div content on button click, from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/feqnLs6o/

I am trying to refresh `<div id="refreshableDiv">` on `button1` click, using jQuery.
I want to load the content of `http://shiro-desu.com/scr/test/test.php` to the `<div>` every time the `button1` is clicked.
As i haven't used jQuery before, i fail to understand why the following doesn't reload the content of div.

script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#button1').click(function(){
        $.post(
        "http://shiro-desu.com/scr/test/test.php",
        {
        },
        function(data){
        $('#refreshableDiv').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

test.php

```
<?php echo "543"; ?>
```

html code:

```
<div id="refreshableDiv">Primary content</div>
<input type="submit" class="button1" name="button1" value="Reload"/>
```

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/feqnLs6o/

Comment: You are using an id-selector(`#button1`) but the button don't have an id. Also you are trying to make a cross domain ajax request(Same Origin Policy).. you need to enable CORS for that...

Comment: @ArunPJohny i added id="button1" http://jsfiddle.net/feqnLs6o/3/ , and it doesnt work, i do not know what CORS is , could you perhaps edit this fiddle so that it works ? if thats possible since its only 5 lines code

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)([Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)) has to be enabled in the server side... for PHP [see this](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html)

Comment: @ArunPJohny this should go in my `test.php` file ?   `<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for your reply, problem was that it running on jsfiddle i see what you mean now , thanks a lot , also the id="button1" was the problem, it worked great on my server

Comment: yes... if your code also runs in the same domain as your script then there is no need to do that

Comment: can i ask something more, in my website , i will have a lot of `<div id="refhreshable"` , each `<div>` will have exactly one `button` inside. However want to refresh only the div of the button that was clicked! do you know how could i achieve that ? i dynamically create `<div>s` and `<buttons>` with php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62465/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-shiro).

Comment: @ArunPJohny is it possible to prevent a certain `<div id="NotRefhreshable">` in my page  from refreshing ?  for example, when i click an `<a href=?var=value>` and i get redirected to `www.mysite.com/?var=value` , can i stop a `<div>` from refhreshing ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny just trying to make my mp3 player in my website not stop playing when i click links

Comment: @ArunPJohny i suppose i have to make a different function for every single `<a href>` case and do it that way ? is there some easier way ?

Comment: you need to prevent the default action in the click handler - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/feqnLs6o/5/

Comment: @ArunPJohny i opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198595/jquery-ajax-make-part-of-a-page-div-not-refresh-on-website-navigation

Answer (score 0):

Just change your html code of button to:

```
<input type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" value="Reload"/>
```

You are using id when binding click event.

Comment: It is just because you are making cross domain Ajax request. If you want to test in fiddle just change the URL to /echo/html and pass html data in data parameters like {html:'<p>test</p>'}

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're not posting any data - it would make more sense to do an AJAX GET Request instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.button1').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url:'http://shiro-desu.com/scr/test/test.php'
     }).done(function(response) {
        $('#refreshableDiv').html(response); 
     });
 });
});
```

Inspecting console log for the request shows the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://shiro-desu.com/scr/test/test.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access. fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:1

Putting:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

At the top of http://shiro-desu.com/scr/test/test.php should solve that issue.

It's in regards to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy